# Java program to print vowels in an array?

Tags: java, return, return-value

I am writing a program to find the number of vowels in each word within an array. I have the code finished, I am just unsure of what the return value should look after the if statement.

```
public static int vowels(char [] array, int x, int y) {
    if(array[x]=='a' || array[x]=='e' || array[x]=='i' || array[x]=='o' || 
                                         array[x]=='u' || array[x]=='y') {
        y++;
    }
    if (x < array.length) {
        x++;
        vowels (array, x, y);
        return ???;
    } else {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for trying recursion.I think returning y should do. Try it and then tell us

Comment: what is the meaning of `y`?

Comment: Since the answer is quite obvious, it seems like a task for learning recursion. So, I recommend you to try write this function completely on you own, and ask you tutor instead of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
vowels (array, x, y);
return ???;
```

You should return the value, computed by vowels, since it is a clean function, and doesn't has side effects:

```
return vowels (array, x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly-

```
private static String vowelString = new String("aeiou");
public static int vowels(char [] array) {
        int x=0;
        for(char ch:array) {
            if(vowelString.indexOf(ch)>=0)
                x++;
        }
        return x;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion here it is a very ugly solution. It would be much more simpler, if you rewrite it so:

```
public static int vowels(char[] array) {
    int y = 0;
    for (char x : array) {
        if (x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u' || x == 'y')
            y++;
    }
    return y;
}
```

But if you actually need use recursion (e.g. it is your homework, and it is your task, that you must use it), then you need to fix some mistakes in your code and remove `y` argument - it is unnecessary:

```
public static int vowels(char[] array, int x) {
    int y = 0;
    if (array[x] == 'a' || array[x] == 'e' || array[x] == 'i' || array[x] == 'o' ||
            array[x] == 'u' || array[x] == 'y')
        y++;
    if (x < array.length - 1) {
        x++;
        y += vowels(array, x);
    }
    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- First, I would prepare a **map** of vowels.
- Second, I would iterate over my array and check each element whether
  they exist in the map. If they exist, update the counter. Otherwise,
  continue to check other elements.

*Sample code:*

```
Map<String, String> vowels = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
        put("a", "");
        put("e", "");
        put("i", "");
        put("o", "");
        put("u", "");
        put("y", "");
    }
};

String input = "blablabla";
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    if (vowels.containsKey(input.charAt(i) + ""))
        counter++;
}
```

Comment: Why not then use HashSet... :?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution to the program -

public class so {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    char array[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'x', 'h', 't', 'd' };
    System.out.print( vowels(array, 0, 0));
}

public static int vowels(char [] array, int x, int y) {
    if(array[x]=='a' || array[x]=='e' || array[x]=='i' || array[x]=='o' || 
                                         array[x]=='u' || array[x]=='y') {
        y++;
    }
```

Note that in x should be less than array.length-1 since its value is getting incremented. Otherwise it will throw an **index out of bounds exception**.

```
    if (x < (array.length-1)) {
        x++;
        return vowels (array, x, y);

    } else {
        return y;
    }
    //return -1;
   }
}
```

Cheers,